# Is there a way to plot the sum of all the rows that have the same name

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

[This is a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqYoi.png) of my dataframe and the code that i tried in order to plot the sum of all the genres global sales
[This is a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N67Ea.png) of what the graph

excuse me for the bad description of the problem, i did not know how to describe it

Comment: Please don't post pictures. Post your code and data which can be copied.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the series you need:

```
genre_sales_df.groupby('Genre').sum()['Global_Sales']
```